# php include with html css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php file that i include in other php files. This php file is the menu. It links to my stylesheet with `<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet/index" type="text/css" />`. But this only works if the php file that includes it is correct according to the path. How can I use absolute paths?

Say if I include the menu.php from another folder how can you **automatically** update the path to the css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet/index" type="text/css" />
```

It means `styles/main.css` from root of website

Answer (score 3):

Just use the absolute path, `href="/style/main.css"`

Answer (score 2):

An absolute URI is like this:

```
href="http://example.com/absolute/path/to/file.css"
```

an URI relative to the current directory is like this:

```
href="relative/url/to/file.css"
```

an URI relative to your site's root (http://example.com/) starts with a /:

```
href="/relative/path/from/yoursite/to/file.css"
```

Inside your css file all URLS are relative to it's own position so it's behaviour doesn't change when the path of the file which includes it changes.
In example if your menu.css file is located into

> http://example.com/styles/menu.css

just use

```
<link href="/styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet/index" type="text/css" />
```

And browsers will always look for menu.css in http://yoursite.com**/styles/menu.css**

Comment: Those are both relative URIs. An absolute URI will stand alone (i.e. it must start with a scheme).

Comment: That's right, I only wanted to emphasize but used wrong terms. Edited and added a couple of examples.

Comment: @Quentin that's quite absolute path

Answer (score 1):

Use the full path relative to your document root instead of the relative path. E.g.

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet/index" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

as you suggested, just you absolute paths. So when you link to your stylesheet, just use the the full path like `http://www.mysite.com/css/myCssFile.css`

Comment: That's an absolute URI, not just an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

By the way *always* make sure you put a base tag on your HTML, like that:

```
<base href="http://www.mysite.com/" />
```